# SharePoint list validation formula

Tags: list, validation, formula

I need help with the following: I have 2 columns in a list and when "Yes" is selected in column 1, then "Yes" must be selected in column 2 also

What I need is:

If `[column 1]="Yes"`, then `[column 2]` must be `"Yes"`.

in other words, If `[column 1]="No"`, then `[column 2]` can be `"No"` or `"Not Applicable"`)

It would be great if anyone could help me with the right formula.

Comment: What is the data type of your columns? Choice or Boolean (Yes/No)/anything else?

Comment: And what you want to do If [column 1]="No"? Can [column 2] be anything in this case or it should only be either "No" or "Not Applicable" (and not "Yes")?

Comment: Column 1 is a choice to force the users to select the right answer and not leave it default. if they select no in column 1, they can select anything in column 2. I put your formula and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF([column 1]="Yes",IF([column 2]="Yes",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

This will satisfy the condition: If [column 1]="Yes", then [column 2] must be "Yes".

Comment: It works perfectly! thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Simona, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you. so that it will help others in future to find the correct answer easily.